# Out-of-the-box opencv installation for python on windows

Tags: python, windows, opencv, installation

Is there any "Out-of-the-box" installation method for opencv for python on windows?
I'm looking for something like `pip install opencv`, or similar for a package that contains most common scientific libs and opencv.

I know only the installation method wherein I compile opencv with the Python support flag, and then manually copy the necessary files to the python folder.

I am aware of the prebuilt packages at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, but they are out of date.

I'm using Anaconda IPython and it seems an opencv package is available only for Linux (http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkgs.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [pre-built Libraries on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/) contain the 32 Bit python module under build/python/2.7. You just need to copy it to Anaconda x86's library and you're all set.

If you need x64 under Windows you have to make them yourself, I believe.

Comment: I recall that downloading and installing the executable from SourceForge is all that's necessary.

Comment: But that's just a self-extracting archive. Python has to be made aware of the cv2 module somehow, either by copying it into lib or by setting a PATH of some kind to your extracted OpenCV folder.

Comment: I recall it installing it directly into the default library location, and so the installation is as automated as possible. Again, this is all from memory, so I might be wrong.